# Unable to access mongo db through mongoose running in docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./reactapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  server:
    build:
      context: ./expressapp
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

node js code

```
function connectToMongoDB() {
    return mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017').then(() => {

    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setTimeout(() => {
            connectToMongoDB()
        }, 10000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 'mongo' as the hostname, not 127.0.0.1

Comment: I need to use mongo because that's my service name in compose file?

Comment: Yes. if under `services`, you had named it `mongodb`, then you would be using 'mongodb' as the hostname.